# Memory leak detection at runtime in an iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, memory-leaks

Is there a way to programmatically find out the memory leak at runtime in an iPhone application?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not programatically.. But there is the [Leaks tool](http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/) that comes bundled with Instruments and XCode.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically find the current memory stats using vm_statics object. Go through these links to find an implementation of vm_statistics:

1)http://gamesfromwithin.com/whered-that-memory-go

2)http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/Determining_Available_Memory.20081203.html